# Are "a perfect fool", "a proper fool" and "a precious fool" the same kind of "fool"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, word-usage

Is there any (subtle) difference in meaning and usage when these adjectives qualify "a fool"?  Are these adjectives perfectly interchangeable

- "A precious fool I would look, if I did that."
- "The officer made me look a proper fool."
- "You are a perfect fool!"

Comment: If used, they mean the same thing. The intensifier 'real' is more common. 'Proper' is more colloquial than your other two suggestions, which sound dated and in the register say the Brontes wrote in.

Answer (score 2):

Science has yet to determine the answer to that question.

[image: Far side cartoon, "What kind of fool"]

Comment: Sounds like a cue for a song.

Comment: @Dan Bron  Excuse my computer illiteracy, but how do you post a picture?

Comment: In the full-experience desktop site, there's a picture button on the toolbar, next to **bold**, *italic*, [hyperlink](http://google.com) and so on. In the mobile app, you'll have to use the markdown syntax; the particular syntax for embedding external images is `!(image description)[http://image/url/filename.ext)`. Note the leading exclamation point (**!**).

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd that; it's `![image description](http://image.com/url/filename.ext)`. Note there is no space between the closing square-bracket and opening parenthesis, nor between the `!` and the `[`.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is an old song from the 60s called "What kind of fool am I?"  sung by Sammy Davis Jr.